# Why AJAX doesn't work once I add these code?

Tags: ajax, ms-access, asp-classic

I have a page for deleting ORDER record. This page was called from AJAX, which work perfectly. However once I added some code that I made for updating inventory table at the same time. It seemed that AJAX function became malfunction and I can't figure out what is  wrong with them. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

My AJAX function (order_edit.asp)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
       var HttPRequest = false;
       function doCallAjax(ID) { // delete order
          HttPRequest = false;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
             HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
             if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
             }
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
             try {
                HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
             } catch (e) {
                try {
                   HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
             }
          } 

          if (!HttPRequest) {
             alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
             return false;
          }

          var url = '../engine/delorder_edit.asp';
          var pmeters = "tID="+ID;

          var bill_id = document.getElementById('bill_id').value; // additional for delorder_edit.asp 

            HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);

            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//          HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
            HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


            HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {

                 if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
                  {
                     if(HttPRequest.responseText == 'Y')
                      {                       
                      document.getElementById("tr"+ID).style.display = 'none';
                      }
                  }             
            }

       }
</script>
```

My delorder_edit.asp Page

```vbs
<%
    Option Explicit

    Dim strID

    strID = Request.Form("tID")

    Dim Conn,strSQL,objExec
    Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("../database/TKP.mdb"),"" , ""

'********** *****************************   
'Open recorset in order to add od_qty back to tbl_inventory before this record was removed
'****** Once I added these code, my ajax became malfunction ****** 

    Set rsOrder = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_order WHERE od_id = "&strID&""    )           
    pd_id = rsOrder.fields.item("pd_id")
    od_qty = rsOrder.fields.item("od_qty")
    od_qty = DzToPcs(od_qty)


    strSQL1 = "UPDATE tbl_inventory SET inv_qty_act = inv_qty_act + " & od_qty & ", inv_date =  date() WHERE pd_id = '" & pd_id & "'"
Set objExec = Conn.Execute(sql1)


'*******************************************

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL&"DELETE * FROM tbl_order "
    strSQL = strSQL&"WHERE od_id = "&strID&" "


    Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Response.write("Y")
    Else
        Response.write("N")
    End IF





    Conn.Close()
    Set Conn = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: open the `delorder_edit.asp` page in browser directly, passing the `tid` as a querystring to check, you will have to modify the `request.form` to `request` in the asp part for the time being to test. check if you see some errors

Answer (score 0):

First of all i will suggest to use the `jQuery.ajax` method to call the server method, so your code will be less and also more convenience to understand. And second thing, debug :

```
 "HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()",
```

and check what value is being returned. Until unless we didn't get a exact error we can not suggest you a solution.